# With TfidfVectorizer, is it possible to use one corpus for idf information, and another one for the actual index?

Tags: scikit-learn, tf-idf, text-classification

using sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer

I want to train a classifier with a Bag of Words tf-idf data.

I have a large untagged corpus, and a smaller tagged corpus.

I plan to use the tagged corpus to build a classifier, based on a bag of words with tf-idf model.
However, I prefer to use the complete corpus (including the untagged data) to compute the idf statistics.

Is this possible when using sklearn?

One solution I thought of was to build a model of all the corpus, and later remove the rows belonging to untagged data. however, the corpus might be to large to store in the ram.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I understand you correctly. You can fit your TFIDF model to all of your data and then call `transform` on the smaller tagged corpus:

```
vec =TfidfVectorizer()
model = vec.fit(alldata)
tagged_data_tfidf = vec.transform(tagged_data)
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @JAB, this is what I was looking for.

Regarding data not fitting in RAM, one may use an iterator, or multiple iterators if the data is spread across different sources. In my case, labelled data was stored in files, while my data was stored in mongoDB:
A file iterator:

```
class File2Doc(object):
    def __init__(self, top_dir):
        self.top_dir = top_dir

    def __iter__(self):
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(self.top_dir):
            for fname in filter(lambda fname: fname.endswith('.txt'), files):
                with open(os.path.join(root, fname), encoding='utf8', errors='ignore') as file:
                    document = file.read()
                    yield document
```

A mongoDB iterator:

```
class Mongo2Doc(object):
        """
        an iterator that builds a find pymongo cursor and saves the text field in the mongodb collection
        """
    def __init__(self, query):
        self.cur = query.cur
        self.text_field = query.text_field

    def __iter__(self):
        for document in self.cur:
            yield document[self.text_field]
```

combining both in a single iterator:

```
class MyDocIterator(object):
    '''
    Expects a list of [folders] (paths) and/or a list of mongoDB [queries]
    mongoDB queries have the form (collection_name, {find_query}, {projection: or text_field})
    example:
    mongo_query = [mongo_client.db.collection, {'optional_query': 'some_value'}, {'text':1}]
    '''

    def __init__(self, folders=None, mongo_query=None):
        self.folders = folders
        self.mongo_query = mongo_query
        if self.folders is not None:
            assert isinstance(self.folders, list), 'folders should be a list'
        if self.mongo_query is not None:
            assert isinstance(self.mongo_query,
                              list), 'Mongo query should be a list'
        if self.folders is None and self.mongo_query is None:
            raise TypeError(
                'Please specify at least one folder or one mongo query')

    def __iter__(self):
        k = []
        if self.folders is not None:
            f = [File2Doc(folder) for folder in self.folders]
            k.extend(f)
        if self.mongo_query is not None:
            m = [Mongo2Doc(query) for query in self.mongo_query]
            k.extend(m)
        return chain.from_iterable(k)
```

usage example:

```
my_docs = MyDocIterator(['path_to_data'])
bow_vectorizer = CountVectorizer(preprocessor=custom_text_preprocessor, tokenizer=str.split)
bow_vectorizer.fit(my_docs)
```

similarly for TfidfVectorizer